# tailwindcss peer-* doesn't work with variable substitution example: `peer-checked:h-[${ht}]`

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying to create a simple div transition using react and tailwindcss.  In the example below, I am trying to shrink / expand a div, based on the checkbox status.

It works if I use a hardcoded value like `peer-checked:h-[240px]`.  But when I use a variable like `peer-checked:h-[${height}]`, then it doesn't work.

```js
import * as React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const height = '240px'
  return (
      <>
        <div className=" bg-blue-200 " >
          Menu div
          <input type="checkbox" className="peer"/>

          {/* working code */}
          <div className={`h-0 peer-checked:h-[240px]
                          overflow-hidden 
                          transition-all duration-500`}>

         {/* NOT working code */}
          <div className={`h-0 peer-checked:h-[${height}]
                          overflow-hidden 
                          transition-all duration-500`}>         

          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
}
```

Is this the expected behaviour with tailwind? Is there a work around to get this variable baed class to work?

Here is the working version which uses the hardcoded value:  https://play.tailwindcss.com/zLA1jM11Lh .

I could not share the react version (non working) as the tailwind playground doesn't seem to suppoort javascript.

Comment: This is expected behaviour as per the documentation. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names
The normal solution is to add as styles or use safelisting, but in this case as you are using `peer-checked` it would require additional CSS to resolve, which someone may be able to help with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could consider using the `style` attribute like:

```
<div
  className="h-0 peer-checked:h-[--height] overflow-hidden transition-all duration-500"
  style={{ '--height': height }}
>
```

Comment: Nice solution. https://play.tailwindcss.com/YLZQsb6gtU